# How can a revert commit also be a merge commit?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, atlassian-sourcetree, git-revert

Recently at work, we lost some code on a project under version control using git (and a private github repository).

I used `git bisect` to find the culprit commit, and I got really surprised discovering it was looking like a revert commit, but also had two parents like merge commits :

```
commit b5f97311eea2905baf8a96fddec22321d952f05c
Merge: 8cc7371 131d463
Author: Bob <bob@othercompany.com>
Date:   Fri May 22 19:42:25 2015 +0200

    Revert "ISB-CPW-3627 - Mise en place du calage des filtres DS1/DS2/DS3/DS4"

    This reverts commit 8cc7371e7133b68db95ac8e9aeb730d7889a1166.
```

This issue has been resolved by creating a new branch from an ancestor commit, and applying some patches on top of that new branch.

**So I don't need help to fix that, I just want to understand how can a revert commit could also be a merge commit, what happened, and how to reproduce this weird behavior.**

I tried to reproduce it like this :

- create a new branch at `8cc7371`
- git revert `8cc7371`

It creates a revert commit with a single parent (`8cc7371`) as expected.

The culprit commit author uses Atlassian SourceTree instead of the native command line interface, so I also tried using the revert feature within SourceTree and got the same result as above (single parent).

After running some git commands on `b5f9731`, I noticed that `git diff` and `git show` are not reporting the same file set :

```
$ git diff b5f9731..8cc7371 --name-only
=> 2 files :
   application/sites/frontend/views/scripts/Layout/Foobar/PointsDeVente/index.tpl
   public/media/design/frontend/css/main-dev.css
$ git show --oneline --name-only  b5f9731
=> 1 file :
   public/media/design/frontend/css/main-dev.css
```

[SourceTree](https://329b2778586190902a3208d343f50f753802d8c8.googledrive.com/host/0B_r5cniqe06JfmRCM1FnbV9KdXRONVFoYUhWTnlnZHZuLTlZQjhDUm14VW1WM0pKazNvRnM/sourcetree%20cppv2%2010h59%20-%20cropped%20anonyme.png) and [Github](https://329b2778586190902a3208d343f50f753802d8c8.googledrive.com/host/0B_r5cniqe06JfmRCM1FnbV9KdXRONVFoYUhWTnlnZHZuLTlZQjhDUm14VW1WM0pKazNvRnM/github-b5f9731/) are showing 2 files.

You can find how the graph looks like here : [graph.html](https://329b2778586190902a3208d343f50f753802d8c8.googledrive.com/host/0B_r5cniqe06JfmRCM1FnbV9KdXRONVFoYUhWTnlnZHZuLTlZQjhDUm14VW1WM0pKazNvRnM/graph.html), and some git commands results there : [misc.html](https://329b2778586190902a3208d343f50f753802d8c8.googledrive.com/host/0B_r5cniqe06JfmRCM1FnbV9KdXRONVFoYUhWTnlnZHZuLTlZQjhDUm14VW1WM0pKazNvRnM/misc.html).

Could anybody explain what happened with `b5f9731` ?

Comment: I shall add this post to favourites and use it as a custom How-To-Ask reference for Git-related questions.

Comment: How's the investigation going?

Comment: Today I played with SourceTree's interactive rebase feature and wasn't able to reproduce the issue. I suppose this problem has something to do with `git rebase` or `git pull --rebase` but I give up. I doesn't have enough information, 3 weeks ago when it happened, I asked the commit author to send me his reflog for further investigation and he was not able to do so. He works on another company (they work on front end whereas my company work on server side), communication is difficult. The mystery remains :s

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863227/rename-a-merged-commit-without-losing-that-commits-parents

Answer (score 1):

What comes to my mind:

```
git revert ...
# new commit abcdef
git merge ...
# new commit fedcba
git rebase -i HEAD~2

pick abcdef - the original revert commit
squash fedcba - the merge commit
```

Message is taken from `abcdef`.

This all results in the new `b5f9731`. It has two parents from a merge commit and the message from the revert commit.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good idea. I expected something simpler than interactive rebase (because the commit author is a beginner), but indeed, SourceTree handles this feature.

Comment: @Vince the benefit of GUIs is that they allow mass destruction by a button click (usually unintended).

Answer (score -1):

Steps to revert the commit from local branch are as following:-

1) Execute the  "git log -1" command on git bash
2) Get the "committed GUID" from above command
3) Execute the "Git reset --hard committed GUID" command on git bash